# How does containTheSameElementsAs work in specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

This code does not match. Is this correct?

```
List(1, List(2, 3, List(4)), 5) must containTheSameElementsAs(List(5, List(List(4), 2, 3), 1))
```

Error message is following:

```
[error]   x be available for elements in a sequence
[error]    List(1, List(2, 3, List(4)), 5)
[error]      is missing: List(List(4), 2, 3)
[error]      must not contain: List(2, 3, List(4)) (specs2test.scala:98)
```

Comment: Note that the type you are using, `List[Any]`, is a type that should never appear in ordinary Scala code. In a statically typed language, using `Any` is a last resort suitable for unusual and extreme situations — not something you should be trying while you're making your first steps with the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `containsTheSameElementsAs` matcher only goes one level deep, so the match fails on your nested list as `List(2, 3, List(4)) != List(List(4), 2, 3)`.  It might be better to simply flatten your nested object before using this matcher.